# ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label: array(['N', 'Y'], dtype='<U1')

Tags: machine-learning, python, data, data-analysis, anaconda

```py
X = train_encoded_df.iloc[:, 1: ]
y = train_encoded_df["Loan_Status"]

print("Precision:",metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

My training data contains the categorical features encoded using `get_dummies()`.

This is causing the error:

```
> ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label: array(['N', 'Y'], dtype='U1')
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pos_label` is an argument of scikit-learn's `precision_score` ([docs)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html); its purpose is, well, to indicate which label is the positive one and, if not given explicitly (like in your case here), it assumes the default value of `1` (again, check the docs).

Since it seems that the positive label in your case is `'Y'`, replace the last line with:

```
print("Precision:",metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred, pos_label='Y'))
```

Comment: I have encoded the "Loan_Status" before training the data to  model and this also resolved the error

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

print("Precision:",metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted'))